# When creating a view in IOS 7's loadView method of UIViewController, why does UIScreen's mainApplication frame begin beneath status bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to create my view programmatically.  I understand that as of IOS7 the status bar overlaps the view.  When I create my view in loadView like this, the frame starts at x/y 0,20 and not 0,0 as I'd expect, and my gradient background does not extend to the top of the screen beneath the status bar.

```
- (void)loadView {
  UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

  CALayer *layer = [MyCustomGradients darkBlueToLightBlueGradient];
  layer.frame = view.frame;
  [view.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];

  self.view = view;
}
```

If I do not override `loadView` and instead set my gradient background layer in `viewDidLoad` on the automatically created view property, the frame's origin is correct at 0,0 and the background is displayed as desired.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
```

returns screen bounds without status bar. Just use

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
```

instead and view will be positioned properly.